# Integer to real conversion function

Tags: type-conversion, vhdl, real-datatype

Is there a common conversion function to convert a integer type object to a real type in VHDL?
This is for a testbench so synthesizability is a non-issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can convert integer to real as follows:

```
signal i: integer;
signal R: Real;

...

R <= Real(i);
```